# How can I control my distance from the final boss?

Tags: the-wonderful-101

If you read further and don't expect unmarked spoilers, I don't know what to say.

In the final phase of the final boss battle, it seems like a crapshoot as to whether I'm close enough to punch Jergingha's weak points or too far away to hit them with anything but Gun or maybe a level 5 Sword, and it doesn't appear that I can do anything to move towards or away aside from waiting for him to do a long-range meteor toss and teleport back at a different range. It's especially annoying to try and reach his feet. How does this positioning work?